# Is it possible to perform a deep property comparison dynamically in Swift at runtime?

Tags: swift, uikit

Let's say we have two instances of `UILabel` that, to us, are equivalent:

```
let label1 = UILabel()
label1.text = "Hello world"

let label2 = UILabel()
label2.text = "Hello world"
```

Let's say the two instances are in an array of type `[UIView]`:

```
let views: [UIView] = [label1, label2]
```

Is there any way to perform an equality check that would find these two instances of `UIView` to be equivalent without knowing which type they are ahead of time (and therefore which common properties to compare on)?

(Any way to use the fact that these instances are both have a `dynamicType` of `UILabel` and dynamically run through the key/value properties of the `UILabel` class and compare each value that can be compared?)

What's happening:

```
label1 == label2      // false
views[0] == views[1]  // false
```

What's desired:

```
areTheSame(label1, label2)     // true
areTheSame(views[0], views[1]) // true
```

We are looking for a way to compare two separate instances, so we can't use `===`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swift has no reflection so this is not possible. We can't even get a list of attributes.

Also note that for many types there is no definition of equality. Even comparing two floating point values is a problem.

Exactly for this reason we have the `Equatable` protocol. If you want to compare types, define equality on them. That equality can then go as deep as needed, without the need for any dynamic (unsafe) behavior.

Just to explain another corner case, for example, on `UILabel` there are some properties that you definitely don't want to compare, namely things like `nextResponder` or `superview`. Trying to deep compare those properties would actually end up in a loop. Usually it's not possible to compare two objects for equality without knowing exactly what should and what should not be compared.

Comment: Thank you. I had a feeling reflection wasn't going to be around, but I was unsure with `Mirror` what was allowed and in-style and what wasn't.

Comment: Do you think it'd be crazy to keep a list of properties to compare per subclass of `UIView` to get this kind of similarity/equality check? Sounds like that might be the only way.

Comment: @sahandnayebaziz It depends how you want to do it. A protocol based solution as seen in http://stackoverflow.com/a/37034228/669586 is probably the best solution. You can extend any view with that protocol and define what you want to compare there. You can also use inheritance.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
let views: [UIView] = [label1, label2]

func areTheSameLabel(view1: UIView, _ view2: UIView) -> Bool {
    guard let label1 = view1 as? UILabel,
          let label2 = view2 as? UILabel else { return false }
    return label1.text = label2.text
}

print(areTheSameLabel(label1, label2))  // Should print "true"
print(areTheSameLabel(views[0], views[1]))  // Should print "true"
```

In response to your comments, I think the best avenue is to create a protocol:

```
protocol ViewEquatable {
    var backgroundColor: UIColor? { get set }
    var text: String? { get set }
    // add any other properties you want to compare here...
}
```

Then write a function to compare them:

```
func ==<T: ViewComparable>(lhs: T, rhs: T) -> Bool {
    return (lhs.backgroundColor == rhs.backgroundColor) &&
           (lhs.text == rhs.text) &&
           // whatever other comparison tests you need go here...
}
```

Something like that is probably your best option, though your requirements are too vague to give a complete answer...

Comment: This would be great if I knew they were both of type `UILabel` and I also only wanted to compare on `UILabel.text`. However, I'm looking for equality between two objects in an array of type `UIView` whose `dynamicType` could be anything, and to compare on equality for as many key/value properties as possible to be accurate.

Comment: Are the objects you are comparing of the same type? Or will you be comparing a `UIButton` with a `UILabel`, etc...

Comment: They will share a superclass (so they both fit into a `[UIView]` array). If one is a `UIButton` and one is a `UILabel`, we can return `false` by comparing their `dynamicType`. If they are both `UIButton`, and say they are both simple instances of `UIButton` that were given the same `UIButton.title` and nothing else, I would like to be able to say they are equal by comparing the `title`, `backgroundColor`, and anything else I can possibly compare that `UIButton` carries.

Comment: With the end goal of knowing that if you removed the first from a simple view and placed the other, there would be no difference.